# error #1267 en SQL(phpmyadmin)

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

Al intentar ejecutar este código en SQL:

```
SELECT userID FROM wcf1_user WHERE password = sha1(CONCAT(salt, 'sha1(CONCAT(salt, "bfe879f0218227e07f9eac09ed13d4c57b754137"))'))
```

Obtengo este error y no realiza la busqueda:

```
#1267 - Ilegal mezcla de collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) y (utf8mb4_unicode_ci,COERCIBLE) para operación '='
```

¿Hay alguna manera de solucionar esto y que funcione correctamente?

Answer (score 0):

Una forma, y la más lógica en mi opinión, sería poner todas las tablas con la misma 'collation' (o 'cotejamiento' en español).
Si accedes a la base de datos desde phpmyadmin tendrás que cambiarlo después de entrar en la tabla > 'Operaciones' > 'Operaciones de la tabla'
Tú elegirás cuál dependiendo de ciertas preferencias, si vas a tener juegos de caracteres muy diferentes (romanos, cirílicos y otros al mismo tiempo, por ejemplo), etc., pero siempre es mejor que utilices una misma codificación de caracteres en todas las tablas.
De todos modos, si ya tienes datos en las tablas es mejor que hagas una copia de seguridad antes o que trabajes con una base de datos que no esté en producción, por supuesto.

Hay un buen análisis en https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-unicode-sets.html. Está en inglés, pero quizá no sea un problema.